# SQL for each group find column order by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregate

Here's the data:

```
studentid,state,score,date,modno,transactionno
1,IL,10,20170101,0,0
1,VA,20,20170102,1,1
1,FL,30,20170103,2,2
2,VA,40,20170101,0,0
2,IL,50,20170102,1,1
2,IN,60,20170103,2,2
```

Here's how the output should be:

```
studentid,state,score,date
1,IL,20,20170101
2,VA,60,20170102
```

So basically we want to group by studentid.

Find the first state based on the lowest modno and transactionno.

Find the first score based on the highest modno and transactionno.

```
select studentid,
       (select top 1 state from student s1 where s.studentid = s1.studentid order by modno, transactionno) as state,
       (select top 1 score from student s1 where s.studentid = s1.studentid order by modno desc, transactionno desc) as score,
       (select top 1 date from student s1 where s.studentid = s1.studentid order by modno, transactionno) as date
from student s
group by studentid
```

Above is my query in SQL 2008.  Are there other ways to write this query to get better performance?  It really shows down when working with large data sets and with pulling out more than two columns per group.

Comment: Why does a `studentid` column have multiple rows in a `student` table?

Comment: I am not understanding output. What *date* should be used? Why 20 for id - 1? Shouldn't it be 30?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would approach this with conditional aggregation:

```
select studentid,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then state end) as state,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then score end) as score,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then date end) as date
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by studentid order by modno, transactionno) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by studentid order by modno desc, transactionno desc) as seqnum_desc
      from student s
     ) s
group by studentid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess your output is not correct or we havn't unserdtood Date part in your output.

Try this other sample data and let us know,

```
declare @t table(studentid int,states varchar(20), score int
,dates date,modno int,transactionno int)

insert into @t VALUES
(1,'IL',10,'20170101',0,0)
,(1,'VA',20,'20170102',1,1)
,(1,'FL',30,'20170103',2,2)
,(2,'VA',40,'20170101',0,0)
,(2,'IL',50,'20170102',1,1)
,(2,'IN',60,'20170103',2,2)
;with CTE as 
(
select studentid from @t
group by studentid  
)
SELECT t.studentid,ca.states,ca1.score,ca.dates 
from CTE t
cross apply(select top 1 t1.states,t1.dates from @t t1 
where t.studentid=t1.studentid 
order by modno,transactionno )ca
cross apply(select top 1 t1.score from @t t1 
where t.studentid=t1.studentid 
order by modno desc,transactionno desc )ca1
--cross apply(select top 1 t1.dates from @t t1 
--where t.studentid=t1.studentid 
--order by modno ,transactionno  )ca2
```